# How can I disable react-number-format input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-number-format

I'd like to disable `react-number-format` input, but this component doesn't have `disabled` property.
How can I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disabled` is working fine.

I have placed 2 components, one without the `disabled` attribute and the other one with the `disabled` attribute and the result is the desired one.

```
  <NumberFormat
    value={111}
    thousandSeparator={true}
    prefix="$"
    className="some"
    inputmode="numeric"
  />
  <NumberFormat
    value={222}
    thousandSeparator={true}
    prefix="$"
    className="some"
    inputmode="numeric"
    disabled
  />
```

Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-marco-ukthcx?file=/src/App.js) sandbox

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering you can also show the number just as text. You can use the [displayType](https://s-yadav.github.io/react-number-format/docs/props#displaytype-text--input) prop.

```
  <NumberFormat
    value={69}
    thousandSeparator={true}
    prefix="$"
displayType="text"
  />
```